# How to replace second or more occurrences of a dot from a column name

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Folks, how can I replace second occurrence of a dot from column names?

Sample data:

```
age.range.abc = sample(c("ar2-15", "ar16-29", "ar30-44"), 200, replace = TRUE)
gender.region.q = sample(c("M", "F"), 200, replace = TRUE)
region_g.a = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 200, replace = TRUE)
physi = sample(c("Poor", "Average", "Good"), 200, replace = TRUE)
survey = data.frame(age.range.abc, gender.region.q, region_g.a,physi)
head(survey)
```

I tried this but it removes all dots with underscore. I want to replace only second or more occurrences with underscore.

```
names(survey) = gsub("\\.", "_", names(survey))
names(survey)
# [1] "age_range_abc"   "gender_region_q" "region_g_a"      "physi"
```

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the spirit of your original code:

```
names(survey) = sub("(\\..*?)\\.", "\\1_", names(survey))
names(survey)
[1] "age.range_abc"   "gender.region_q" "region_g.a"      "physi"
```

A little extra detail in case it helps.

`\\.` matches the first `.`
`.*?` The `.` matches any character. `.*` matches zero or more instances of any character. But the matching is greedy; it would match as much as possible.  I want matching that is not greedy (only up until the second `.`) so I added ? to suppress the greedy match and `.*?` matches any group of characters up until we hit the next thing in the regex which is ...
another `\\.` to match the second `.`.
Because the first part was enclosed in parentheses `(\\..*?)` it is stored as \1, so the substitution pattern `\\1_` restores everything before the second `.` and the second `.` is replaced with the `_` .

Comment: "little extra detail" was very helpful G5W

Answer (score 1):

One option is `strsplit`

```
names(survey) <- sapply(strsplit(names(survey), "[.]"), function(x) 
    if(length(x) >1) paste(x[1], paste(x[-1], collapse="_"), sep=".") else x)
names(survey)
#[1] "age.range_abc"   "gender.region_q" "region_g.a"      "physi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` with `(\\.[^.]*)\\.` where

`\\.` matches `.`

`[^.]` matches everything but not a `.`

`*` match it 0 or more times

The brackets `(` `)` are used to store the match, here in `\\1`:

```
sub("(\\.[^.]*)\\.", "\\1_", names(survey))
#[1] "age.range_abc"   "gender.region_q" "region_g.a"      "physi"
```

To be more explicit `^([^.]*\\.[^.]*)\\.` can be used where the first `^` indicates the start of the string:

```
sub("^([^.]*\\.[^.]*)\\.", "\\1_", names(survey))
#[1] "age.range_abc"   "gender.region_q" "region_g.a"      "physi"
```