# replacing second occurence of string with different string

Tags: r, regex

I have very simple issue with replacing the strings second occurrence with the new string.

Lets say we have this string

```
string <- c("A12A32")
```

and we want to replace the second `A` with `B` string. `A12B32` is the expected output.

by following this relevant post
[How to replace second or more occurrences of a dot from a column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077846/how-to-replace-second-or-more-occurrences-of-a-dot-from-a-column-name/43078093)

I tried,

```
replace_second_A <-  sub("(\\A)\\A","\\1B",  string)
print(replace_second_A)

[1] "A12A32"
```

it seems no change in the second `A` why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that .*? matches the shortest string until the next A:

```
string <- "A12A32"
sub("(A.*?)A", "\\1B", string)
## [1] "A12B32"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no need to escape the letter `A` using backslashes. They are only required to escape special characters that have other meanings *e.g.* "." means "any character", "\\." means "period".

Second, your regular expression "(\\A)\\A" reads "match A followed by another A, keeping the first A for reuse." You don't have two consecutive "A", they are separated by digits.

So this works ("\\d+" means "match 1 or more digits"):

```
sub("(A\\d+)A","\\1B",  "A12A32")
[1] "A12B32"
```